# Python:merge data frame with different rows

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two data frame with different rows and without common key:

df1:

`name | age | loc`

`Bob  | 20  | USA`

df2:

`food  | car    | sports`

`Sushi | Toyota | soccer`

`meat  | Ford   | baseball`

result I want:

`name | age | loc | food  | car    | sports`

`Bob  | 20  | USA | Sushi | Toyota | soccer`

`Bob  | 20  | USA | Meat  | Ford   | baseball`

my code below:

`pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',left_index=True,right_index=True)`

it works well when df2 is more than two rows but be incorrect when df2 is only one row.

any ideas for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) by index of `df2`:

```
df1 = df1.reindex_axis(df2.index, method='ffill')
print (df1)
  name  age  loc
0  Bob   20  USA
1  Bob   20  USA

df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',left_index=True,right_index=True)
print (df)
  name  age  loc   food     car    sports
0  Bob   20  USA  Sushi  Toyota    soccer
1  Bob   20  USA   meat    Ford  baseball
```

---

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `ffill` (`.ffill`) if no `NaN` data in `df1` and `df2`:

```
#default outer join
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).ffill()
print (df)
  name   age  loc   food     car    sports
0  Bob  20.0  USA  Sushi  Toyota    soccer
1  Bob  20.0  USA   meat    Ford  baseball
```

---

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',left_index=True,right_index=True).ffill()
print (df)
  name   age  loc   food     car    sports
0  Bob  20.0  USA  Sushi  Toyota    soccer
1  Bob  20.0  USA   meat    Ford  baseball
```

Comment: Hi,@jezrael, Thank you for your help. your idea is great when row number of df2 is more than 1, but it does not work when df2 has only one row in it.

Comment: And solution `df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).ffill()` does not work?

Comment: it will result a new dataframe with two rows even my original df1 and df2 are both one row.

Comment: Hmmm, then what is logic? Because if use merge with `left_index=True,right_index=True` it means join by indexes - if in both is 1 row, then both indexes are `0` and output have one row with `0` index. Same works with `concat`. Maybe help [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: but if merge with one df with one row (index is 0) and second with 2 rows (indexes are 0,1) then if use `how='inner'` (inner join) then get only first row, because match 0 index in both dataframes. But if use left or right join or outer join, get 1 or 2 rows, but second is full of `NaN`s, because no match.

Comment: Thanks, @jezrael, I will try to use right join and let me see what will be happen

Answer (score 1):

Another type of solution... based on concat.

```
x = range(0,5)
y = range(5,10)
z = range(10,15)
a = range(10,5,-1)
b = range(15,10,-1)
v = range(0,1)
w = range(2,3)

A = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x,y=y,z=z))
B = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a,b=b))
C = pd.DataFrame(dict(v=v,w=w))

pd.concat([A,B])
>>> pd.concat([A,B],axis = 1)
   x  y   z   a   b
0  0  5  10  10  15
1  1  6  11   9  14
2  2  7  12   8  13
3  3  8  13   7  12
4  4  9  14   6  11
```

@Edit: based on the comments.. this solution does not answer the question.. Because in the question the amount of rows are different. Here is another solution
This solution is based on the dataframe D

```
n_mult = B.shape[0]
D = C.append([C]*(n_mult-1)).reset_index()[['v','w']]
pd.concat([D,B],axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, @zwep, your idea is great when df is more than one row, but does not work well when df2 has only one row.

Comment: Hi @zwep， Thank you for your idea. i have already resolved this issue with reset_index. thank you all the same.